# Kinect with windows adapter worked once, adapter or kinect broken?

Tags: windows, kinect

I have purchased a Kinect v2 with windows adapter. 
I connected it yesterday and it worked fine. Today it does not work anymore. 
How can I tell if the problem is the adapter or the kinect itself?
If I connect the kinect to the adapter, the XBox logo does not light up, should it? Or will it only light up when connected to the USB port when it is communicating with the PC?
If the Kinect should be broken and is plugged in the PC, would it turn up in device manager anyway or not?
How can I pin point the exact problem?

Comment: I work with Kinect for windows V2. It doesn't light up when I connect it with my pc, it lights up when I start using some application which requires Kinect. And, when I stop using that application, Kinect lights turn off, though Kinect is connected to PC.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the info. So it is not clear wether it is the kinect or the adapter... 
I have connected it to an xbox one, but I was not able to try to use it with a kinect game: will it light up on connecting to this device? It does not in my case.

Comment: So far I know, Kinect for windows v2 has a service in the OS. The service regulates Kinect. When any application needs Kinect data, the service wakes Kinect up and serves required data. As soon as the application stops asking for kinect data, or the application closes, the kinect service stops kinect. Keep in mind that, Kinect v2 Service can simultaneously provide data to more than one application. The service will keep kinect running, if at least one application ask kinect data. If no application need kinect data, it stops kinect.

Comment: ok thank you for your help.